# AngularJS remove scope variable in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to remove scope variable if I pass it into function without calling it from $scope?

```
// controller
$scope.user_id = 1;

$scope.example = function(uid) {
    // remove $scope.user_id without accessing it like a scope
    // smth like 

    uid = null; // won't work
};

// html
<div ng-click="example(user_id)">Click me!</div>
```

So I want to have completely isolated function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you're going to be able to remove the property from `$scope` is via `delete`. If you need to dynamically reference the object (ie `$scope`) and the property, try passing the key as a string, eg

```
ng-click="example(this, 'user_id')"
```

and

```
$scope.example = function(scope, key) {
    delete scope[key];
};
```

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you!

Comment: @NG I've added a more *"isolated"* example